# If two vector spaces are isomorphic, does that guarantee that there's a linear transformation $T$ that is an isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $T: V \longrightarrow W$ and $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic vector spaces, does there always exist a $T$ that is an isomorphism?

Comment: Usually the definition of isomorphic is that an isomorphism exists. What is your definition?

Comment: but of course that $T$ need not be the same $T$ you started your sentence with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{V}$ and $\mathbb{W}$ linear spaces over the **same field** $\mathbb{K}$.

If $\mathbb{V}$ and $\mathbb{W}$ are isomorphics, so **exists** a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{V}\longrightarrow \mathbb{W}$ such that $T$ is injective and surjective.

You do not assume that the $T$ function exists. This follows from the fact that $\mathbb{V}$ and $\mathbb{W}$ are isomorphic.